# Yii2 - How make a dropdownlist with a database and show fields from the selected value

Tags: php, html, frameworks, yii2, yii2-basic-app

With Yii2, I'm trying to make a dropdownlist from a database (already done) but show the fields from the selected value.

Example :
Table :
Immeuble

- Immeuble_id
- Immeuble_name
- Immeuble_propetary
- Immeuble_color

This is my code :

Model :

```
class Imm extends ActiveRecord{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'i10';
    }

    public function attributeLabels(){
        return array(
                'N_NUME_IMME'         => 'N_NUME_IMME',
        );
    }

}
```

Controller :

```
public function actionImm($id)
    {
        $model = new Imm(); // envoyer le model sur imm.php
        $query = Imm::find(); // trouver le model       

        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

        $imm = Imm::find()->where(['N_NUME_IMME' => $id])->one();

        $items = ArrayHelper::map(Imm::find()->all(), 'N_NUME_IMME', 'L_NOM1_COMP');
        return $this->render('imm',['imm'=>$model,'imm'=>$imm, 'items'=>$items]);

    }
```

views :

```
    <h1>Immeuble : </h1>            
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'login-form',
                'layout' => 'horizontal',
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-6\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-6\">{error}</div>",
                    'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
                ],
            ]); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">      
                     <?= Html::activeDropDownList($imm, 'N_NUME_IMME',$items, ['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'liste_immeubles'])?> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Chaufferie', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'bouton_']) ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Locaux communs', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'bouton_d']) ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Parking/Amenagements Ext', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'bouton_donnees_generales']) ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Facades/Toitures', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'bouton_don']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>        
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

            <h2>Donnees Generales</h2>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?= $form->field($imm, 'C_MODE_CHAU')->textInput(['autofocus' => false]) ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
```